# Just storing XML/JSON in a DB for data not used within the DB?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, xml

I have a small database with some basic user data in it (uid, username, email, password, etc) which is used by various SQL queries and PHP so having a full table structure there makes sense.

However a new feature will add a few new tables where each user will "own" a number of rows in these tables (say 100KB of data for each user). However from the DB standpoint, all I really want to be able to do is either set all the data for one user, or get all the data for one user.

The data will then only ever be viewed and edited client side, using JavaScript. Of course the JavaScript can not directly run the SQL queries, and after the data is edited and submitted as a HTTP POST, trying to put together the correct set of UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE queries in PHP by tracking whatever changes were made by the user that session is somewhat complicated.

Instead what I am thinking is to just have a TEXT field in the database for each user, and store JSON or XML in it. The JavaScript can then just be given that to populate the HTML table and after the user is done editing that table the JavaScript just needs to collect all the data back from the HTML form and post it. The PHP then just needs to run an SQL query to overwrite the existing data.

While this seems the simplest way, it does seem to be a bit of a misuse of an SQL DB. I am also wondering if it is better if the initial before-edits table was generated by PHP in the first case, not the JS once the document has loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Using a text field to store data for cases like yours is a common practice. However, if you decide to do that move, take into consideration the following issues:

- **Stick to a fixed format.** If you store data as plain text, be aware that the database will no longer use its mechanisms to ensure data integrity and format unification. So if you have a few records with a given format, then change it and add a few more with the new format, those with the old format will no longer work, unless you ensure that you support both formats. So, your data format should be mature and consistent enough.
- **Estimate data length.** You should have a good idea of how long the data text will become, in order to guarantee it will fit the database column you are storing it in. Some databases have issues with unlimited data type columns (like `TEXT`) so you should know your db server well, as well the deployment configuration. Usually MySQL and PostgreSQL will not have issues, but in my experience I have faced serious problems with Informix - so your database server matters.
- **Do not rely on client code**. You mention to be creating the data via javascript. I recommend at least submitting the JSON to the server and producing another JSON from it to store in the database, or validate it in some other way. Otherwise, it may be possible for a hacker to add malicious content, or perform DB injection, or otherwise compromise your application if you do not take measure when free-form client data is added. If, however, the data is entirely generated on the server, the risks are fewer.

So, in general, this is not a bad practice in terms of database development, but as you see, provides additional considerations. If you figure them all out (I do not pretend to include all in my list, just the most common that I have personally faced), then you will be OK.